# Trouble Dowloading Hadoop and extraction Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, installation

I am trying to download hadoop. Java is installed so that hasn't been a problem. When I try to install hadoop on my computer though it is a blank file and windows 10 asks me what program to run it on, and none seems to work. I then try to use 7-zip to extract the file but nothing is extracted. Any thoughts on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the complete name of the file you are trying to run/unzip?

Answer (score 0):

Just open 7-zip and run as administrator and choose your file which needs to be extracted. This trick worked for me hopes this works for you too...